# How to validate Playwright locators in Visual Studio Code without executing tests?

Tags: javascript, debugging, playwright, relative-locators

I am working on test automation using Playwright in VSCode (JS). Before completing the entire functionality, I want to verify whether my locators are correct.
Currently, I can only see if a locator works by using that locator during test execution. Is there something like 'pick locator' tool that allows me to input a locator and preview the highlighted elements in the browser view? Alternatively, are there any other efficient methods to check locators within the development environment?

Upon expecting the "pick locator" feature to accept user-provided locators, I found out instead that it can only display the locator of the selected element.
Also this "pick locator" doesn't work for me because it produces bad locators with a lot of text fields that won't work in real test runs.

Comment: There's no other way to verify that your tests work besides running them, experimenting and developing skill in choosing proper locators. Codegen doesn't always work, nor does ChatGPT. Websites are highly dynamic, unique beasts that you can't really just eyeball or statically analyze to determine a set of locators.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

If you have the browser loaded, e.g. after you have played the last of your test steps, you just need to click on the locator definition in your test in vscode. If it is visible in the browser it will be highlighted. This has been a feature of Playwright for quite a long time now so if your versions of Playwright and the vscode extension are fairly up to date it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Playwright with [Inspector](https://playwright.dev/docs/debug#playwright-inspector) to validate your locators during a test run

```bash
npx playwright test your_test.spec.ts --debug
```

or add

```js
await page.pause();
```

to run a test from a specific breakpoint.

From there you can edit and preview locators.

[image]